# Why does this substitiution not work when calculating flux

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

The problem in my book is verbatim:
"Find the flux of $\mathbf{F}=x\mathbf{i}+z\mathbf{j}$ out of the tetrahedron bounded by the coordinate planes and the plane $x+2y+3z=6$"

One of sides of the tetrahedron is $\mathcal{S}$ that is bounded by the coordinate axis of the $yz$-plane and the plane $2y+3z=6$.

As can be easily seen from the force $\mathbf{F}$ the flux is paralell to $\mathcal{S}$ and so the flux out is $0$

However naivly continuing as if the flux is nonzero: we find a normal $\mathbf{N}$ to the plane $\mathcal{S}$ is $(-1,0,0)$ which gives
$$\iint_{\mathcal{E}} \mathbf{F} \bullet dS = \iint_{\mathcal{S}} -x dA=\iint_{\mathcal{S}}(2y+3z-6)dzdy $$
The last integral is nonzero. Infact
$$\iint_{\mathcal{S}}(2y+3z-6)dA=\int_{0}^{3}\int_{0}^{2-\frac{2y}{3}}(2y+3z-6)dzdy=-6$$
Why is this so?

PS [There exists](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2690945/find-the-flux-of-f-x-mathbf-i-z-mathbf-j-out-of-the-tetrahedron-bounded-by) a solution to solving the entire problem but I am only concerned with this particular aspect of it.

Comment: if the flux is in the $\mathbf{ij}$ plane, it may be not parallel to ${\mathcal{S}}$ (in the $yz$-plane)

Comment: How is the flux parallel to $S$?

Comment: @Allawonder I thought it to be paralell to $\mathcal{S}$ As $\mathbf{F}=0\mathbf{i}+z\mathbf{j}=z\mathbf{j}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner is it not parallel to $\mathcal{S}$ as the $\mathbf{i}$ component is $0$?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski That does not follow. It is only parallel to any surface of the form $x=0,y=0.$ Otherwise, it is not.

Comment: @Allawonder I see, But is it then the case that the flux out is not zero at $\mathcal{S}$, i.e the second integral is correct?

Comment: @AndréArmatowski I've not checked the integral, but the force is definitely not parallel to $S.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a lingual mixture between planes and lines. One of the faces of $S$ is lying in the $(y,z)$-plane $\pi: \>x=0$. This face is a triangle $T$,  bounded by the $y$-axis, the $z$-axis, and the line $2y+3z=6$ in $\pi$.

As you correctly remark the field ${\bf F}$ is parallel to $\pi$ in the points of $\pi$. This immediately implies that the flux through $T$ vanishes. For the computation we would have to compute
$$\int_T{\bf F}\cdot d\vec A=\int_T(x,z,0)\cdot(-1,0,0)\>dA=\int_T0\>dA=0\ .$$
The $(2y+3z=6)$-business only has to do with the exact boundaries of $T$. It would be necessary to go into these details when computing the double integral in case the integrand is not $\equiv0$ on $T$.

Note that Gauss' theorem tells you that the desired flux is equal to  ${\rm div}({\bf F})\equiv1$ times thes the volume of the given tetrahedron.